# Как создать видеоплеер на c#?

Tags: c#, видео, mediaplayer

Хочу создать видеоплеер на c#,но везде видел только варианты с WMP или VLC,но это не то. Мне нужен свой плеер с тайм лайном,паузой,перемоткой и.т.д. Кто подскажет способ?

Comment: Нашёл через Google статью: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level26/26_2.php

Ключевое: вам надо научиться разрабатывать WPF приложения, то есть обычные оконные приложения. Для них есть готовые компоненты `MediaPlayer` и `MediaElement`.

Comment: спасибо! помогли

Answer (score -3):

береш стандарный браузер что в списке контролов и
**результат** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri($"{Application.StartupPath}\\src\\index.html", UriKind.Absolute));

            }
```

вот так можно работать с элементами

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("video").SetAttribute("src", "urlvideo");
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="./x.mp4" autoplay controls></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Зачем ему вебраузер? Ему полноценный плеер видеофайлов нужен

Comment: ну так это и есть полноценый плеер

Comment: Через браузер? Мсе знает толк в извращениях)

Comment: Вы видимо про electron не слышали   а тут просто закос под него

Comment: Причем тут электрон?

Comment: Бтв так можно про любую задачу сказать у которой есть онлайн реализация :D воткнуть в программу браузер и открыть в нем сайт с рабочим решением

Comment: Про электрон я в курсе. Но это стрельба из пушки по воробьям - использовать браузер для таких вещей, более того, браузеры поддерживают ограниченное количество форматов. Да и нафига вообще так делать?

Comment: принцип тот же.  пользовательский интерфейс на основе web  технологий. проблема в том что это win forms  и  это самый просто способ сделать то что ему надо при учете что он отказался от  стандартного плера конечно надо юзать не стандартный браузер а CefSharp. CefSharp  это хромиум думаю там проблем сформатами не будет

Comment: ну к примеру visual code   отличный  пример оконого приложения на  HTML